# How to preview IBM MobileFirst 8.0 cordova application on android device

Tags: android, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

Can anyone let me know the process to preview IBM MobileFirst cordova application on Android device.

I am able to preview on console but unable to preview on mobile.

System Details:
Eclipse version:Mars.2 Release(4.5.2)
IBM MobileFirst Version:8.0.0.v20170425_0443

Comment: Preview on mobile? Have you tried running the application on your device? Like cordova run?

Comment: I need solution in IBM Mobilefirst,cordova commands won't work for me because I have integrated cordova project into IBM Mobilefirst

Answer (score 1):

You can do :

```
cordova run
```

or

```
cordova emulate
```

or open the Android project in Android Studio and run it on a device or emulator.

Refer to this [link](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/cli/) for cordova commands.

Comment: I have integrated cordova project into IBM Mobilefirst,I think cordova commands won't work for me.I need solution in IBM Mobilefirst

Comment: Clearly, you are making comments without even trying. With MFP 8.0, you create standard Cordova applications using Cordova CLI and add MFP as a plugin to it. Finally you build and execute as you would any Cordova project. Refer to :
https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/application-development/sdk/cordova/